# Dropbox links in a Phonegap app (Android)

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, webkit, dropbox

I try to create downloadable links to files which can be downloaded directly after clicking the link. I added "dl" instead of "www" and "?dl=1" in the end of the dropbox link ([dropbox api: Force a file or folder to download](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en)). The direct download works perfectly in the chrome browser but if I package the app with phonegap for android and click on the same link whithin the resulting app the file will not be downloaded. Is this not possible whithin the android browser or do I have to modify some android browser preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the version of phonegap. It works with Phonegap 2.0 and as far as I remember with phonegap 1.4 too, but not between 1.5 and 2.0, and not above 2.0.